# media print & border property not working

Tags: css, printing, bootstrap-4

I want to hide my left & bottom border on a table. Working fine, but not when I'm trying to print my page.

I'm using border-bottom & border-left properties.

```
td.border-fix {
    border-left:1px solid red;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
```

CodePen here : https://codepen.io/Barthandelous/pen/ZdEPdd

Actually the borders are in red for the example, and you'll notice that the borders aren't red when you try to print the codepen page.

In my project, I'm setting those borders to white as a "hack" to hide them.

Any idea why this doesn't work and how to make this possible ?

EDIT : I'm running on Google Chrome, latest version.

Comment: Have you tried to print the page outside of codepen?

Comment: Yes. Same result. @Nisharg Shah provided the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you can use `@media print`, to overwrite property I used `!important` property.

By clicking right in mouse, you see one option called print, In print now you can see `red border` on your table.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KjwqZR

Comment: I forget to mention that I was using a style tag with media="print" but this doesn't seems to work. By the way, your solution works fine. Thanx !

Comment: glad you like my answer